# verify a google id token and use data from callback in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, google-signin

In my react app I retrieve an authorization token from google and send it to my back end to verify it. I followed https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth to achieve this, but I need to use the data I get in the callback outside of the callback:

```
const clientId = '<MyAppId>';
var auth = new GoogleAuth;
var client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, '', '');
client.verifyIdToken(
    input.googleAuthToken,
    clientId,
    function (e, login){
       if (login) {
           var payload = login.getPayload();
           var googleId = payload['sub'];
           console.log(googleId); //correct id is logged
       }
    }
);
//I need the 'googleId' here
```

So this is working, but I need the googleId outside of the callback to check it with my database. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, `client.verifyIdToken` is async, so there is no way to wait for the return value in javascript in pure synchronous way. But, you can write and execute async functions in a sync manner (but it is still asynchronous under the hood, and the JS execution continues) for instance with promises.

Consider a few changes to your code:

```
const verifyToken = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    client.verifyIdToken(
        input.googleAuthToken,
        clientId,
        function (e, login){
           if (login) {
               var payload = login.getPayload();
               var googleId = payload['sub'];
               resolve(googleId);
           } else {
            reject("invalid token");
           }
        }
    )
}).then(function(googleId){
    //use googleId here
}).catch(function(err){
    //error
})
```

So we create a promise that take a function with two parameters: resolve, and reject. These are functions that you call when you get your value asynchronously. By doing that, you can use `.then` syntax that takes a function that will be executed after the previous function in the chain resolves (with a value you specified, in this case googleId token). Read more about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Google Developer Console and generate an API key, then the verification made easy. (with `"google-auth-library": "^1.1.0"`)

```
const { auth } = require('google-auth-library');
const client = auth.fromAPIKey('<YOUR_API_KEY>');

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { idToken } = req.body; // idtoken from your react app

  const res = await client.verifyIdToken({ idToken });

  const { email, name, picture, sub: googleid } = res.getPayload();
  const user = { email, name, picture, googleid };

  // transform to your local user
  // ...

  res.send(authUser);
});
```

Don't forget to hande exceptions.

Hope this help.